# Approximate value of a function at a point

Tags: linear-transformations, partial-derivative

I was asked to compute the approximate value of a function near a point (2.2 ,-0.2)

Using partial derivative and linearization of course 
But when I looked up the answer it was evaluated for the partials at another close point THEN substituted with the given point in the final form of L(x,y)

Now why is that ? Why wasn’t the point used from the start ?

Here’s the full thing : 
[image]

Comment: Because $f$ and its linearization would agree at $(2.2, -0.2)$ had you used that point. Plus, there's an easier choice of point to evaluate at - $(2, 0)$.

Comment: Curiously, the “true” value that is given for $f(2.2,-0.2)$ is off by quite a bit starting at the thousandths place.

Comment: @sarah  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that by the approximation in (2,0) you can a**void the calculation of the exponential** $e^{2y}$ for y=0.2 that's quite difficult by hand whereas at (2,0) it is equal to 1.